# Remediation for Unsafe Cryptographic Encryption error

Tags: android-security

Remediation for Unsafe Cryptographic Encryption how to fix this issue.?

Any way to fix this issue.

Security alert

Your app contains unsafe cryptographic encryption patterns. Please see this Google Help Centre article for details.

Vulnerable classes:

```
com.vpapps.utils.g.a
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a static key used in your encryption you just need to move that key to another configuration file or something like that.
hope this fixes your problem.

Comment: I removed the static key from code to another config file still the warning persists